What happens to the instances of classes created within a constructor of another class?
I am trying to learn the basics of C++ classes and have written the code below
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
using namespace std;
// defines a 'point'
class Point {
public:
    double x;
    double y;
    // can also double x,y;
    // Constructors. Can have multiple constructors. This is possbile thanks to overloading feature
    // Constructors are all configured using the method with same name as class name.
    Point() {
        x = 0.0;
        y = 0.0;
        cout << "A point was created with default setting! Its address is " << this << endl;
    } // default constructor places point at origin
    Point(double nx, double ny) {
        x = nx;
        y = ny;
        cout << "A point was created! Its address is " << this << endl;
        // Point.x = nx, Point.y = ny
    }
    // Copy Constructors. Do not need to define explicitly if you don't want some special features
    // a point class is passed by reference (&o)
    // Why define it? maybe you just want x coordinate of point to be copied or print some messages when copied.
    Point(Point& o) {
        x = o.x;
        y = o.y;
        cout << "A point was copied from address " << &o << " and its points had addresses " << &o.x << " and " << &o.y << endl;
        cout << "Copied point has address " << this << " and its points has addresses " << &x << " and " << &y << endl;
    }

    string coordiate() {
        return "(" + to_string(x) + "," + to_string(y) + ")";
    }
};

// Vector is composed of two points, start and end
class Vector {
public:
    Point start;
    Point end;

    Vector() {

    }

    Vector(Point x, Point y) {
        start = x;
        end = y;
    }
};

class VectorByRef {
public:
    Point start;
    Point end;

    VectorByRef() {

    }

    // if you specify arguments to constructor, then vector is created by reference to the points. 
    // if the points in question changes, vector also changes.
    VectorByRef(Point &x, Point &y) {
        start = x;
        end = y;
    }
};

int class_example() {
    Point start; // put a point at origin
    cout << "Its coordinates are (" << start.x << "," << start.y << ")\n";
    Point end(1.0, 1.0); // put a point at 1,1
    cout << "Its coordinates are (" << end.x << "," << end.y << ")\n";
    Point foot(1.0, 0.0); // put a point a 1,0
    cout << "Its coordinates are (" << foot.x << "," << foot.y << ")" << endl << endl;

    // Copy a point
    cout << "Copying a point..." << endl;
    Point copy_end = end;

    cout << endl << endl << "Creating a new vector..." << endl;
    Vector uVec(start, end);
    cout << endl << endl;

    cout << "a vector with start and end points specified has been created " << uVec.start.coordiate() << " " << uVec.end.coordiate() << endl;
    cout << "its points has addresses " << &uVec.start << " and " << &uVec.end << endl;
    return 0;
}

When run, following results are printed
> A point was created with default setting! Its address is
> 0000001C17AFF5D8 Its coordinates are (0,0) A point was created! Its
> address is 0000001C17AFF608 Its coordinates are (1,1) A point was
> created! Its address is 0000001C17AFF638 Its coordinates are (1,0)
> 
> Copying a point... A point was copied from address 0000001C17AFF608
> and its points had addresses 0000001C17AFF608 and 0000001C17AFF610
> Copied point has address 0000001C17AFF668 and its points has addresses
> 0000001C17AFF668 and 0000001C17AFF670
> 
> 
> Creating a new vector... A point was copied from address
> 0000001C17AFF608 and its points had addresses 0000001C17AFF608 and
> 0000001C17AFF610 Copied point has address 0000001C17AFF858 and its
> points has addresses 0000001C17AFF858 and 0000001C17AFF860 A point was
> copied from address 0000001C17AFF5D8 and its points had addresses
> 0000001C17AFF5D8 and 0000001C17AFF5E0 Copied point has address
> 0000001C17AFF8A8 and its points has addresses 0000001C17AFF8A8 and
> 0000001C17AFF8B0 A point was created with default setting! Its address
> is 0000001C17AFF698 A point was created with default setting! Its
> address is 0000001C17AFF6A8
> 
> 
> a vector with start and end points specified has been created
> (0.000000,0.000000) (1.000000,1.000000) its points has addresses
> 0000001C17AFF698 and 0000001C17AFF6A8

and my concern is about what's happening to the "copied" points.
According to the printed results,

Original points have addresses 0000001C17AFF608 (end point) and 0000001C17AFF5D8 (start point)
Copied instances of above points are created at 0000001C17AFF858 and 0000001C17AFF8A8 respectively
Default points are created when vector class is initiated at 0000001C17AFF698 and 0000001C17AFF6A8
The values at the initiated points then change to that of copied points

But what happens to the copied points that are created in the middle, 0000003F9EDAF578 and 0000003F9EDAF5C8 ? Are they automatically deallocated from the memory?
Can't we just "set the values" of 0000003F9EDAF3B8 and 0000003F9EDAF3C8 to the values of end and start points without creating a copy so to save a piece of memory?

I can't read the text in the picture, it's tiny, 5x smaller than the regular text on my phone. Please post the output as a text in a code block.

Yes, your code creates temporary Point instances that are automatically destroyed. To get a more complete picture, instrument the destructor (~Point) and a copy assigment operator (operator=), in addition to constructors.

"what happens to the copied points that are created in the middle..." Follow/use the rule of three/five and everything will be revealed.

In addition to the rule of three, note that Point(Point&) is an unusal signature of copy constructor and you should really have written Point(const Point&) instead. Vector(...){start = x; end = y;} is also not the typical way to write a constructor. You should use the member initializer list instead, that is, you should write Vector(const Point& x, const Point& y):start(x),end(y){}. Those less familiar with C++ tend to think using the initializer list is the same as assignment in the body, but they are really not equivalent.

Also, don't get into the habit of using namespace std;. If you don't pay attention it will backfire one day or the other.

Side note return "(" + to_string(x) + "," + to_string(y) + ")"; replace with std::format("({},{})", x, y);

Also NEVER initialize your members inside the body of your constructor, but use constructor initializer lists. e.g Point() : x{0.0}, y{0.0} {}, Point(double nx, double ny) : x{nx}, y{ny} {}

It's better to post the output as a code block, not a quote.
